# android L preview; ndk make failed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to test my application on the android L preview.

This build success with all other android versions!

If I change the Android Build Target to Android L (Preview), Eclipse tells me following:

```
[2014-07-23 08:29:00 - XYZ] Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'L'
```

But if I follow this Instruction, and change following

```
android:minSdkVersion="9"
```

to

```
android:minSdkVersion="L"
```

My console tells me

```
D:/XYZ/android-ndk32-r10-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r10/build/gmsl/__gmsl:512: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: 'L'.  Stop.
```

and I have following error in the Problems:

```
make: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: 'L'.  Stop.   XYZ     line 512, external location: D:\XYZ\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9d\build\gmsl\__gmsl   C/C++ Problem
```

Does anybody had the same problem and know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance
lukas

Comment: Have you tried using the latest NDK version (r10)?

Comment: @Michael, after your comment I updated my NDK to r10. But the problem still remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the platform "L" is supported only in the ndk r10 *for 64 bits targets* (you can still use it to compile for 32 bits targets).

You can either use this release or declare `APP_PLATFORM:=android-15` (where 15 is your current minSdkVersion) inside your Application.mk, to compile your sources against it instead of android-L, which makes more sense if it's for testing compatibility.